# React Router v6.0.0-beta0 - Animating route transitions with TransitionGroup and CSSTransition

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-transition-group, reactcsstransitiongroup

My app has two routes: `Step1` and `Step2` and a `Next` button that takes you from `Step1` to `Step2`. I would like to animate the transition between `Step1` and `Step2` so that when the user clicks `Next`, `Step2` slides into view from the right while `Step1` slides out of view to the left.

This works in React Router v5.2.0 ([**v5.2 demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-w-csstransition-suz0e?file=/styles.css:0-925)), but **not** in v6.0.0-beta0 ([**v6 demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-w-csstransition-duv8c?file=/styles.css)).

- In the v5.2 demo, when you click `Next`, you can see that `Step1`
  transitions out and `Step2` transitions in as expected.
- However, in the v6 demo, when you click `Next`, `Step1` is immediately replaced by `Step2` and the exit transition is applied to it, so
  that `Step2` appears to be entering and exiting at the same time.

I think this might be due to the `<Routes>` component (which is the v6 equivalent of `<Switch>`, see migration guide [here](https://morioh.com/p/995f1244f33b)).

According to the [v5 docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions) (line 48), you must pass the location object to `<Switch>` so that "it can match the old location as it animates out". `<Switch>` then uses this object instead of `context.location` to match the path ([see line 19](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L19)):

`const location = this.props.location || context.location;`

...whereas `<Routes>` just reads location from the context ([see line 532](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L532)):

`let location = useLocation() as Location;`

I think this explains the behaviour in the [**v6 demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-w-csstransition-duv8c?file=/example.js) - you can see that the exiting route is re-rendered from `<Step1>` to `<Step2>` as it is exiting, is this correct? How can I prevent this re-render?

Comment: It looks like you've found the current open issue. Basically the current implementation doesn't check for the `location` prop and therefore doesn't manage the exiting route correctly. A PR to fix it exists, but unfortunately the main React Router devs appear to be on hiatus while focusing on another project.

Comment: @jymbob yes, I wasn't aware of the [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7297) when I posted here. Someone suggested using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to fix it, which worked well for me even though the source is minified.

Comment: To patch it, I included `react-router` as a peer dependency in my `package.json` and modified `/node_modules/react-router/index.js` according to the [PR](https://github.com/MeiKatz/react-router/blob/location-prop-for-routes/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L619). I then applied the patch and the transition animation worked as expected.